# What to do if using utf-8 while writing in a file results in replacement of some characters?

Tags: python-3.x

Writing some raw text + html data into file with these lines:

```
ready_file = open('example.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
ready_file.write(raw_data_html)
ready_file.close()
```

If I'm using encoding, it results in some characters, such as ' and ", being replaced with вЂќ, вЂњ, Ђ™ and so on.
If I'm not using encoding, it results in this type of errors:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character 'X' in position Y: character maps to 
>   undefined

IF i'm writing only text data withour html part and not using encoding as in example below:

```
ready_file = open('example.txt', 'w')
ready_file.write(raw_data)
ready_file.close()
```

then it's fine and no ' or " are being replaced with вЂќ and so on.

How do I avoid this error or avoid my characters being replaced with god knows what?

UPD: figured it out! I had ” instead of " in my initial files.
Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the data that do and do not get converted to garbage characters

Comment: Regardless of anyone expaining what is going on to you in an answer, please read https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/  (it is a 2003 article from the creator of Stack overflow himself)